# Angular 7 e2e connect ETIMEDOUT, tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor

I want to use e2e tests in my Angular project using protractor. Running `ng e2e` will cause a error

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.201.112:443
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

I followed [this](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy) setup. First I set up Windows environment `HTTP_PROXY` variable.

[image]

Then I created `src/proxy.conf.js`so it looks like this.

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server
var proxyConfig = [{
  context: '/api',
  // target: 'http://your-remote-server.com:3000',
  target: 'http://172.24.61.70',
  secure: false
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
    proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry) {
      entry.agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

Lastly I added `serve` to `architect` in `angular.json`.

```
"architect": {
    "e2e": {
      ...
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "my-portal:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Now I am getting an error:

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8080 8080:80
at ClientRequest.onError (C:\projects\star-card-frontend\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

---

**EDIT**

For som reason [tunnel-agent](https://github.com/request/tunnel-agent) is receiving bad proxy options:

```
{  
   host:'8080',
   port:0,
   proxyAuth:null,
   headers:{  
      host:'chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, digging the `node_modules` revealed that parser in `url.js` used in `tunnel.js` parsed my `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable but it expected complete ulr with protocol. So adding protocol into `HTTP_PROXY` => `http://172.24.72.10:8080` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set proxy in your protractor config. Set stg like that:

```
config = {
    capabilities: {
        proxy: {
            proxyType: 'system'
            httpProxy: process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. `capabilities` has no `proxy` prop. Look at [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)